# adjtimex usage on Linux server

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, c, c++

I want to change my system clock(rate - speed) on Linux server, Can I directly use adjtimex command from terminal like #adjtimex? or is there a specific syntax/script to call this command? Let me know thanks

Answer (score 1):

At least on Debian, there is an `adjtimex` package you can install, which gives you a command that will make the kernel syscall for you (with some of the fields)

But adjtimex isn't used to set the clock. Instead, it changes how *fast* the clock runs (similar to `tickadj`). If you want to set the clock—tell the system what the current time is—`date -s` does that.

If you have a network connection, considering using `ntp` to set the clock and keep it accurate.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, Is it also available for Linux Server - RHEL6.7?

Comment: @Mat55 it appears not to be. They seem to recommend using tickadj instead (see https://access.redhat.com/solutions/63391 though note I haven't read more than the preview since I don't have access). Of course, you could grab the source code and compile it yourself.